# Java datatype for sudoku grid

Tags: java, sudoku

I am currently trying to plan/write a sudoku solver in Java.
The aim is for me to learn as much as I can about the language (as a beginner).

The solver will not be a "brute-force" solver, but will instead be a system of functions that implement logical algorithms, capable of being completed by a human.

But which data type do I use?

- ArrayList of ArrayLists
- 2D array
- Something Else

I know in a lot of cases it comes down to preference and features, but, because I am looking to implement a number of "solve" functions, I need a 2d data-type that I can iterate over quickly and efficiently and avoid repetitive code (such as nested for loops).

Which data type provides the best 2D iteration?

Comment: Well if you want to avoid nested for-loops, you could try a 1D array.

Comment: for sudoku, tic-tac-toe, etc. type of games 2-D array is always your best option (more like simpler). It's even cooler in C++ as the memory blocks can be assign contiguously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2-D array is probably your best option since sudoku grids are fixed:

```
byte[][] grid = new byte[9][9];
```

It will definitely give you the best space and computation performance (even though you will observe no difference on a small 9x9 grid!).

Now if you are more comfortable using an other data structure or wants to play with a more object-oriented one, go for it and enjoy the language.

Answer (score 0):

A two dimensional array is probably the best solution. An array of array lists does not make much sense because ArrayLists are designed to be of dynamic size which is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing your own datatype based on a 2d-array. You can implement a method like "iterate" or "return all cells" to avoid repetitive nested foor-loops and still access all elements. 
ArrayLists are useful if the size of your field would be unknown or need to be dynamic for whatever reason but since sudoku always has a 9x9 grid you wont need that and if you just started learning java you should stick to the basics (in this case wrapping a class around a 2d-array which is a good start imho). 


Just one more point why you should use a 2d-array: 
It is very easy to return/check/solve a column or row using a 2d-array since rows and columns share one common index on the sudoku grid (and so they do in your 2d-array).

This might be a point for you to start from. Nothing more than a small inspiration.

```
class Sudokugrid{
    private int[][] field;
    Sudokugrid(){
       this.field = new int[9][9];
    }
    public int get_cell(int x, int y){
       return this.field[x][y];
    }
    public void set_cell(int x, int y; int value){
       this.field[x][y] = value;
    }
    //(...)
}
```